# Python and Jinja2 - Import template of another environment

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I am trying to build a project that uses Jinja2 tempalting. I would like to have a sort of template library that I could import in many other projects. The problem I have is that I can't find a way to include/import a template from this library from within the template of my project.

As an example, we could use the same example that we find in Jinja2 documentation [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#macros)

File forms.html

```
{% macro input(name, value='', type='text') -%}
<input type="{{ type }}" value="{{ value|e }}" name="{{ name }}">
{%- endmacro %}
```

ProjectPage.html

```
{% import 'forms.html' as forms %}
<dl>
    <dt>Username</dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('username') }}</dd>
    <dt>Password</dt>
    <dd>{{ forms.input('password', type='password') }}</dd>
</dl>
```

This example would works since the "forms.html" template is in the same environment as "ProjectPage.html". Since I can use the macro in many projects, I would like to put it inside a module that I could import later. Doing so, makes the macro template in a different environment and the import statement fails.

Hwo can I make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
I ended up finding a solution not so long after posting my question. Turns out it is quite easy.

It looks like we can pass variables to an environment using the `globals` attribute. We can also make an `import` statement on a template object.

So I pass my library environment to my project environment and I can call `get_template` from my project template.

```
env.globals['mylib'] = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.PackageLoader('mylib', 'templates'))
```

Then in my template :

```
{% import mylib.get_template('folder1/theTemplate.tpl') as mytemplate %}
```

Good day